# RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code. Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java

```
package date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SpeedDatingTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    String CDay = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year: ");
    int cDay = Integer.parseInt(CDay);

    Date date = new Date(cDay);
    System.out.println(date.discoverColumbusDay);

   }

}
```

NetBeans is telling me that "Date date = new Date(cDay)" is giving me a RuntimeException and I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where you Import the `Date` class?

Comment: What is Date, a class you wrote yourself?

Comment: what is `date.discoverColumbusDay` ?

Comment: `RuntimeException` saying `Uncompilable source code` means that you're trying to run code that didn't compile. Fix compile errors before running code. Compile errors are more specific, and will likely tell you *exactly* what the problem is.

Comment: Date is a class given by my professor for us to use. discoverColumbusDay is a method in another class we had to make

Comment: If `discoverColumbusDay` is a method, where are the `()` that are a required part of making method calls?

Comment: Forgot to add (), my mistake. Still gives me the RuntimeException, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an import for the Date class you are using. Unless it is located in the same package as the SpeedDatingTest this could be the cause.

However if it is in the same package than the compiler cannot find the class and you should make sure it is on the classpath.